# Perl Programming and Return Values

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, return-value

How do you return the value of a local variable array (or any variable for that matter) in perl.  For instance.  Must I return a reference to the array. That seems like it wouldn't work as well.

```
sub routine 
{
my @array = ("foo", "bar");  
return @array;  
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  How do you return values from local variables in perl?

My second related question is, how do I access a nested array as an array For instance. The previous question creates the need for this solution as well.

```
@nestedArray = ("hello", "there");  
@array = ("the", \@nestedArray);  

($variable1, $variable2) = values @array;
```

This is what I've tried

```
($variable3, $variable4) values $$variable2; ## This doesn't seem to work?
```

:-/

Comment: How does your first example not work?  What's it not doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: I must have typed it differently :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your second question, you should read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to clear up your understanding of references.

Also, while `keys` and `values` will technically work on arrays, they're not really meant to be used on them.  It's a red herring.

Comment: What is the correct way to extract each value of an array into a list of scalars?

Comment: The correct way to extract each value of an array into a list of scalars is with a straightforward "list assignment", eg ($variable1, $variable2) = @array;

Comment: Thank you :-), I read the reference it was very helpful as well.

Comment: why won't this work then :-/ @animal = ("a", "b", "c");  
@array = ("c", \@animal);  
($a, $b, $in) = @array;  
($c, $d, $e) = @{$in};   
print "HERE $a, $b, $c, $d, $e";

Answer (score 2):

```
sub routine {
    my @array = ( "foo", "bar" );
    return @array;
}

print join "\n", routine();
```

The above indeed returns a list.

```
@nested_array = ( "hello", "there" );  
@array = ( "the", \@nested_array );  

print join "\n", ( $array[0], @{ $array[1] } );
```

Here, the first element of `@array` is `the` and the second element is an array reference. Therefore you have to dereference the second element as an array.

However, for ease, you could flatten the second array into a list:

```
@array = ( "the", @nested_array );
print join "\n", @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, this works:

```
($variable3, $variable4) = @$variable2;
```

Your first example seems to work like you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You typically return references to non-scalar variables, or scalar values directly.

```
return $var
or 
return \@var
or 
return \%var
```

then dereference them as %$var or @$var or use arrow notation

$var->[0] or $var->{hash_key}

Comment: Why not just return the list the array holds?

Comment: Perhaps because the conversion to a list is not the same as returning an array? Not entirely sure, but it's such a common idiom in perl programming I've grown quite accustomed to it.

Comment: In list context, it is the same.  In scalar context, it is different.

Answer (score 0):

For first, you did the right thing. But I think you invoke the function in a scalar context, so you only got the number of elements in the list/array.

```
sub routine 
{
  my @array = ("foo", "bar");  
  return @array;  
}  

my $a = routine(); # a will be **2** instead of an array ("foo", "bar")
my @a = routine(); # a will be an array ("foo", "bar")
```

If you really need to return an array, and want to make sure the sub was invoked properly. You can use `wantarray()` function.

```
sub routine 
{
  my @array = ("foo", "bar");  

  return @array if wantarray;  

  die "Wrong invoking context";
}
```

For second, you could use push;

```
@nestedArray = ("hello", "there");  
@narray = ("the", "world");

push @narray, @nestedArray; # @narray is ("the", "world", "hello", "there")
```